# Id not saved automatically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am creating a simple program in spring boot using **JPA** to show **student** and **phone number** relationship.

**CODE**

**Student Entity**

```
package student.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String name;
    int roll;
    @OneToOne
    PhoneNumber num;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public void setNum(PhoneNumber num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber Entity**

```
package student.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String num;
    String type;
    @OneToOne
    Student stu;

    public PhoneNumber() {
        super();
    }



    public PhoneNumber(String num, String type) {
        super();
        this.num = num;
        this.type = type;
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Student getStu() {
        return stu;
    }

    public void setStu(Student stu) {
        this.stu = stu;
    }



}
```

**Student and Phone number repo**

```
package student.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import student.entity.Student;

public interface StudentRepo extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

}

package student.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import student.entity.PhoneNumber;

public interface PhoneNumberRepo extends CrudRepository<PhoneNumber, Long>{

}
```

**SeedFile to enter dummy data**

```
package student;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import student.entity.PhoneNumber;
import student.entity.Student;
import student.repo.PhoneNumberRepo;
import student.repo.StudentRepo;

@Component
public class SeedDb implements CommandLineRunner {
    private StudentRepo studentRepo;
    private PhoneNumberRepo phoneNumberRepo;

    public SeedDb(StudentRepo studentRepo, PhoneNumberRepo phoneNumberRepo) {
        super();
        this.studentRepo = studentRepo;
        this.phoneNumberRepo = phoneNumberRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("######################");
        Student stu1 = new Student();
        stu1.setName("X");
        stu1.setRoll(4);
        PhoneNumber p = new PhoneNumber("9090909090","Home");
        phoneNumberRepo.save(p); //saving phone number to database
        stu1.setNum(p);
        studentRepo.save(stu1);

    }

}
```

In this program (in seedDb file), I have to manually save the **Phone number** using **phoneNumberRepo** before setting it to the **student** but there are tutorials online where this step is not needed.

Also, the id of **student** is not saved to the **phone number** as shown in screenshot [image: H2 Database view]

Please tell me how to set **PhoneNumber** to **student** without saving it to the database i.e. when I save **student**, **phoneNumber** automatically get saved to the database and how to set id of **student** to the **Phone number** automatically.

Comment: Why do you need to put foreign key in both the tables?

Comment: because my Sir said bidirectional mapping is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you set the PhoneNumber in your Student, but you never set the Student in your PhoneNumber.

As for the bidirectional relationship, you need to use the `cascade` parameter in the `@OneToOne` annotation of one of the two entity you're creating the relationship out of. The rule of the thumb is, cascading should be done from parent to children. In your case, the Student is the parent class, so you should do the following:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
PhoneNumber num;
```

And create a student like so:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("John Doe");
student.setRoll(4);
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("9090909090", "Home");
student.setNum(phoneNumber);
phoneNumber.setStu(student);
studentRepository.save(student);
```

Result:

[image: SELECT * FROM STUDENT]

[image: SELECT * FROM PHONE_NUMBER]

Comment: Thank you @TwiN that worked, but can u suggest a way so that when I save **student phoneNumber** get automatically saved.

Comment: It already does that. Did you make sure that you set the student in the phone number and the phone number in the student? If you did, then saving the student will save both.

Comment: if I don't write **phoneNumberRepo.save(PhoneNumber)** its throws an error ,that means **studentRepo** is not able to save the **phoneNumber**

Comment: Hi @Ankit, just so you know, the preferred way of saying "thanks" around here is upvoting any helpful answers, and accepting one if it helped solve your problem (which will also grant you a few reputation points). If you have additional questions, please create a new, separate question.